# MobileGestalt no access to InverseDeviceID

Tags: ios

This happens with every app when I try to use `OpenGLES` on my `iPhone7+` with `iOS10.3`. But it works without any problems on my `iPhone7` `iOS10.1`.

This is the message I get:

```
libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 304 (OpenGLES_Ch4_1) does not have sandbox access for ... and IS NOT appropriately entitled 
libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:549: no access to InverseDeviceID
```

Does anyone have an idea about these messages?

---

I wonder if it is bugs or something else in `iOS10.3`? Because when I run the app on `iPhone5s` `iOS10.2`, those messages **did not** shown on the screen. While I upgraded the phone to `iOS10.3.1`, the massages shown again.

The reason why I ask this question is that some animation effects perform quite stuck on my iPhone7+, but it is completely smooth on iPhone5s. But now it seems it is no relationship between the message above and the stuck, and I have to check my iPhone7+...

Comment: Hi! Did you fixed? 
I see the same libMobileGestalt messages when I run all my apps using Google AdMob Framework, on my real test device iPhone 6S Plus. No messages when I use simulator.

Comment: No. The message are still shown when running on iPhone.

Comment: This shows up when opening a UIWebView in a storyboard using a push segue... iPhone 7. iOS SDK 11.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. It turns out to be multiple thread accessing the same OpenGLES related resource, `EAGLContext` to be specific. I guess it is possible that OpenGLES related codes are not thread-safe, and it behaves differently in different OS versions / iPhone 7 / 7+, sometimes it messes up the memory.

After making sure data accesses are synchronised across threads, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who are maybe using Ionic and getting this error, please just make sure that in case you've cloned a new fresh copy of the project from your repository that you did both `npm install` and `bower install`.

I was missing `bower install` and this was torturing me for like two days, so hope this helps someone. Sad thing is that I'm by all means not a beginner with Ionic ([top #3](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic-framework/topusers) answerer on SO) but was still able to miss this fact so I hope that in case someone else runs into this problem it will help you.

Comment: Thank you! Had the exact same problem on my end... Have no idea why this error would be connected to a js package manager problem.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I helped! Yes, I too don't know how these are related :/

Comment: It should be made clear in this answer itself that it is relevant to Ionic only, which is not what the original question asks for.

Comment: And did I not write that this is for Ionic users?

Answer (score 1):

**Google Map display and functionality works fine with this warning**

Check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970665/3378076

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue when trying to use in-app-purchases.

Not sure if yours is the same issue, but I realised that you HAVE to create a Sandbox User in iTunes Connect, then log into iCloud on an iOS device with that user to enable the app to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see where the setting up of a sandbox account might do the trick, but if the device you are using is also connected to your normal icloud account, you can't create a sandbox with the same AppleID.
You then have to log out of your existing icloud account, and log in with the new icloud (sandbox) useid. Which screws up your existing icloud device settings.
So you are unable to use your Developer ID, only your Sandbox ID.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Create a new sandbox user in iTunesConnect. YES, you have to create a new iCloud user with a new email.
2. Log OUT your current iCloud user on your mac AND on the device you are testing on.
3. Log IN with your new iCloud user on your mac AND on the device you are testing on.
4. Run your app on your device again. This time it should work.

Hopefully Apple will come around and simplify this issue since this is a real pain in the ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this point me in the right direction:

> I've managed to solve the same problem for MKMapView. Apparently, that happens when your app's current permissions state doesn't correspond to entitled (declared in Info.plist) one. That effecively means that you need to call APIs to gather user's permissions explicitly and preemptively. (E.g. LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization before displaying a map with user location on it)

Source: [rdar://problem/11744455](http://www.openradar.me/11744455)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. My rendering program was written to support 3 version of openglES(1, 2 and 3). On my case I was accidentally supplying `EAGLRenderingAPI.openGLES1 or kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1` to my renderer class based on openGLES2.

Answer (score -2):

I got this console warning message because of issues with multiple Apple Developer accounts.  Evidently you cannot have a sandbox account with an existing Apple Developer account.  I didn't try to create a sandbox account but it seems to check my default account, which is also an old Apple Developer account that I don't use and hence is no longer entitled.  This issue has been reported to Apple many times by other people and I have not yet seen a solution.

My workaround to suppress this warning was to set the **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE** environment variable to **disable** in my scheme settings.  You can click on the app name and then click **Edit Scheme...** or from the top menu you can click **Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme...** :

[image: Edit Scheme...]

Then you edit the "**Run**" settings and add the environment variable **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE** and set it to **disable**:

[image: Run Environment Variables]

**NOTE**:  Be sure to set this environment variable to **enable** before you submit your app so that you can see if there are other warnings.  There may be other warnings you should fix before you submit your app to the App Store.

Comment: Doesn't this just disable ALL warnings? Personally, I find those quite useful!

Comment: Yes, as I indicated in the NOTE at the end.  Set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to "enable" to see the all the warnings again.  I turn it on now and then myself to see and then correct constraint warnings.