# libMobileGestalt: does not have sandbox access and IS NOT appropriately entitled

Tags: ios, xcode

I have downloaded and am working on the following repo:
https://github.com/rootkit/LiveFaceMask

I'm not even sure how to ask this but where would I start to debug the following errors:

```
2017-06-29 21:50:30.529460+1000 LiveFaceMask[311:12995] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 311 (LiveFaceMask) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled

2017-06-29 21:50:30.529546+1000 LiveFaceMask[311:12995] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
```

Comment: found anything?

Comment: I ended up using the repo as is and it worked. I got that error when I built and added / replaced the dlib library files

Comment: [Here's the link to an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45509088/1620701)

Comment: Some of the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/q/43197726/62576 might help. Make sure you look at all the answers, as there are various solutions suggested.