# SpriteKit game fails to load next day on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a game that works great when my iPhone is connected to the SK simulator and for about a day after installing the app from the computer, but after about a day if I try to open it a white screen displays and the app closes immediately before my main menu scene ever displays. Once the app crashes once, it cannot be reopened again after that. I have an iPhone 6 using iOS 10.3.3. It always works the day of installation and then never works the next day, and sometimes will even display my game over scene only in the "task manager" view after double tapping the home button (when I click the app from that view it just takes me back to my home screen).

This is my UIViewController Class:

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = MainMenuScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

}

I also get these error messages overtime I build my app on xCode:

2017-08-24 10:56:54.517973-0500 Laser Space Man 3000[581:110941] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful

2017-08-24 10:56:54.672835-0500 Laser Space Man 3000[581:110775] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled

2017-08-24 10:56:54.673802-0500 Laser Space Man 3000[581:110775] Metal API Validation Enabled

2017-08-24 10:56:54.737885-0500 Laser Space Man 3000[581:110775] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 581 (Laser Space Man 3000) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled

2017-08-24 10:56:54.737987-0500 Laser Space Man 3000[581:110775] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see )

I use a TextureAtlas in my main menu scene, too. (IDK if that could be problematic)

Any ideas on what's going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with certain frameworks, or even just UIKit itself. The main error here is the one that says `libMobileGestalt no access etc` and the `does not have sandbox`

It may also be an issue with your provisioning profile, are you using developer, local team, ??

1. What frameworks are you using? (they may need to be reconfigured, like cordova, ionic, or admob)
2. Do you have a developer account? Are you using that as your provisioning profile?
3. Are you asking to display a content that requires permission, before getting the user's permission?
4. In app purchases?

There is no clear solution here without more information. My best guess is to start a new project, copy everything over, restart your iphone / relog iCloud, and get a new provisioning profile / try changing your signing.

Here are some other threads that may be useful to supplement this answer:

[MobileGestalt no access to InverseDeviceID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197726/mobilegestalt-no-access-to-inversedeviceid)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72286

Answer (score 0):

add following key in info.plist

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>
```

and try again.